# google_fonts doesn't work with Russian Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-fonts

In my Flutter project I am using the `google_fonts: ^ 2.1.0` library. Everything works fine if the text is in English, but if you enter a word in Russian, the font becomes different.

Sample code:

```
Text('Oтменa',
  style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
    fontSize: 48,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    ),
  ),
```

and tried it again

```
ThemeData(
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme(
    Theme.of(context!).textTheme,
  ),),
```

Comment: It might just be that particular font doesn't support Russian. fonts.google.com has a filter to that lets you search for Cyrillic fonts (https://fonts.google.com/?subset=cyrillic). I tried using `GoogleFonts.badScript` font and the Russian text appeared to be rendered correctly with that font.

Comment: according to https://fonts.google.com/ there is Cyrillic version of Montserrat font

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky 
Yes I know. There is a design in figma, and it definitely uses a font from Google Font Montserrat. But I noticed that the design and what happened in Flutter looks different. I also checked Styles in Figma. Everything is one to one, but it still looks different.